# why am I having this error: subscript indices must be either positive integers less than 2^31 or logicals

Tags: matlab

I'm really new to matlab and I was trying this code
but it keeps on showing the same error

```
t = [0:.1:2*pi]; 
sig = sin(t); 
p = [-1:.2:1]; 
c = [-1.2:.2:1]; 
[index,q] =q (sig,p,c); 
plot(t,sig,t,q)
axis([-.2 7 -1.2 1.2])
```

subscript indices must be either positive integers less than 2^31 or logicals
error: called from
    codage.m at line 5 column 10

Comment: You're trying to use `q` as both a variable and a function. Pick a different variable name besides `q` if you have a function by that name

Comment: And pick better names in general. Anything just named `q`, `p`, `c` is pretty bad.

Comment: Agreed with @Suever. Is this file codage.m? You might at one point be asking for the 3.27th compone t of a vector or something like that that doesn't make sense.